# Unconditional distribution of a predictive regression

Tags: regression, predictive-models, stochastic-processes, cumulative-distribution-function

May I preface my question by first apologizing, as I have asked this question in different forms on various occasions. Some questions were perhaps formed incorrectly, predicated on wrong assumptions or asked in a confusing manner. This oversimplification of the problem has been deliberate at times. Now I think I can formulate this question properly and perhaps ask for your guidance:

Consider the predictive regression of the form:
\begin{equation}
y_t=\beta x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t
\end{equation}
where $\beta$ is a coefficient and $x_t$ is a "stochastic" explanatory variable and $\varepsilon_t$ for $t=1,...,T$ are independent error terms such that

\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_t \sim F(.)
\end{equation} 
where $F(.)$ is an unknown distribution function.
Now I wish to evaluate the unconditional distribution function

\begin{eqnarray}
P[y_t<0 ]&=&P[\varepsilon_t+\beta x_{t-1}< 0]\\
\end{eqnarray}

My questions are as follows:

1. if we make arbitrary assumptions on the distribution functions of $\varepsilon_t$ and $x_t$, and assuming the exogeneity of the regressors, how would you go about evaluating these functions? Say $x_t\sim N(0,\sigma_x^2)$ and $\varepsilon_t \sim N(0,\sigma_{\varepsilon_t}^2)$, does that imply we can evaluate

\begin{eqnarray}
P[\varepsilon_t+\beta x_{t-1}< 0]\\
\end{eqnarray}
 using the distribution function 
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_t+\beta x_{t-1}\sim N(0,\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2+\beta^2\sigma_{x}^2)
\end{equation}

2. How would you go about evaluating this if no assumptions are made on the distribution functions?
3. Are there any papers that deal with this that you could recommend?

Comment: $P[y_t<0]$ is a probability (a number between 0 and 1), not a distribution function. $P[y_t<y]$ would be a distribution function if we take the argument to be $y$.

Comment: @RichardHardy It is a probability, perhaps not expressed properly. But we can take the argument $y$ to be zero and evaluate the probability, as I had done in expression $1$ can we not?

Comment: You said *unconditional distribution function*, I just noted it is not. You can evaluate the probability, though.